# To flag and edit, that is the question

Tags: discussion, flags, edits

I recently run into a problem: I flagged a question. Then edited it. Finally concluded that my flag was no longer valid. I started thinking if I should be doing it (flagging and editing at the same time).

If we assume the moderators do a good job, flagging and editing as described above should be OK, because moderators read the latest edit before deciding if a flag is valid or not. But then I started to wonder. What do moderators see? If the edit has not been accepted, will a moderator just see the post at it was when it was flagged? This might lead to some good posts being wrongfully closed due to enthusiastic flagging (people that flag before trying to salvage post, like me). After all, people come to this site searching for help and it can be discouraging to find that your first post was closed.

So, I was wondering what people think about flagging and editing?

Comment: What flag did you cast, exactly? Some flags are *automatically dismissed* when you edit a post.

Comment: That I did not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only flag something if it's something you can't directly do yourself.

For example for users with less than 3,000 rep, you *flag* to close rather than *vote* to close. This puts the question on the close queue for those with more than 3,000 reputation to review.

So if you can edit the post to fix it (remove unnecessary swearing, fix the grammar etc.) then there's absolutely no need to flag the post for a moderator to look at. By making the edit (or suggested edit for those with less than 2,000 rep) you are fixing the post. In fact editing should be the **first** thing you think of doing to a poor quality post. You should only flag if it's irrecoverably bad.