# Edit removing bad language rejected by OP

Tags: discussion

I suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25179553) edit to remove some bad language from an answer. It was subsequently rejected by the OP. The reason given was that the edit deviated from the intent of the post. I don't completely agree with that, especially considering my edit comment was "Replace rude word".

However, looking at it again, I realised that if I had understood the context of the answer a bit better, my edit may have been slightly different, although I still would've removed the bad language. That being said, the difference is really insignificant as it doesn't effect the implementation of the code in the answer. The edited portion in question is only filler text. Regardless, I feel the bad language should be removed.

What I am wondering is what I should do in this case. Should I:

**A)** Suggest another edit that is more in line with the context of the answer (however trivial)?

or

**B)** Flag the question for moderator intervention?

The reason why I feel **B)** may be justified is due to the fact that the the OP could have edited the question to what they deemed appropriate i.e. be in line with the intent of the post, and simultaneously removed the bad language. It was quite clear in my edit comment that the intention was to remove the bad language. Furthermore, I feel that going with **A)** may have yielded a further rejection. Maybe I should try **A)** and then if unsuccessful, try **B)**. What is the best approach?

Comment: I, personally wouldn't say that "bad ass" is bad language. It's just slang. I don't see that the edit was needed.

Comment: **A** is the wrong decision either way; if you really are offended by OP's choice of words then flag it if the OP rejects it; otherwise you just end up in an "edit war".

Comment: It's unusual to have a response header that's related to a misbehaving donkey. But to each their own.

Comment: @Larnu Some cultures and countries have different views of what is considered slang or bad language. StackOverflow is inclusive and should thus keep this in mind.

Comment: @Larnu The reason why I felt  **A** was an option is because the reject reason said that it was not in line with the intent of the post. Why would they not just say "I don't think it is bad langauge"?

Comment: Also, if a post does contain rude language, even if you can fix it by an edit, I think the correct choice is to flag it with the "**rude or abusive**" flag; such language is welcome on SO at all, regardless of it can be "swept away", and the moderators should be handling cases where users aren't respecting the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: Although I agree that different countries have different opinions on words and phrases (I have some European friends that don't understand how offensive a certain word beginning with C is in British Culture) I would humbly suggest that neither "bad" or "ass" are offensive (you use one of those words in your title, and the other is the name of a male donkey, as @yivi pointed out). Had the latter word been another which sounds very similar, and spelt differently (4 letters, contains an r and e) then I would agree more that it *could* be seen as poor language choice and edited out.

Comment: In terms of flagging vs editing, I was following the advice from this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269025/to-flag-and-edit-that-is-the-question

Comment: @Larnu FWIW, I as a brit don't understand *why* a certain word beginning with C is so offensive in our culture... as for bad ass, I wouldn't expect anyone old enough to be on the platform to find it offensive

Comment: C) Let it go...

Comment: @Larnu To be clear, the word "bad" is not what I would deem rude. It's the combination of the two words that I feel in respectful discourse is inappropriate.

Comment: @DanielHolmes On the contrary, I would expect less people to find them offensive when combined, and the latter *on it's own* would be found more offensive. *"Badass"* or *"Bad ass"* is a "word" I remember knowing for..... well as long as i can remember

Comment: I agree with @NickA , here. Calling someone an "ass" and calling someone "bad ass" is very different. One is most definitely an insult, however the other would be used as a compliment. If I were to say to someone "You were bad ass." that would mean they did something impressive; it is miles away from "bad language".

Comment: @Larnu To your assertion that only with an "r" and an "e" would the term be offensive: In non-British English that variation is not used. It's the "a" followed by two "s". Personally, I find it mildly offensive, no matter how it's used. Whether in combination with other words, or not. Part of the reason such a term becomes popular is *because* it's "shocking", due to the content being considered offensive. Other, less controversial terms do exist...

Comment: [Ass Is The Most Complicated Word In The English Language - CONAN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAGcDi0DRtU)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The edit doesn't actually *fix* any issues with the answer besides the notion that you believe that the phrase "bad ass" is bad language.  Note that I'm using it here explicitly in reference to it being what's edited out, and for no other reason.

In all frankness, there's no real value that comes from making this edit.  It doesn't really make the answer any clearer, nor does it improve on what's already there - it's just something to pacify those who believe that the phrase "bad ass" is bad language.

So...I'd say you want to pick "Option C".  **Let this one go**.  *This* is not worth getting into an edit war over.

Comment: Indeed, I will have to go with option C. It's clearly a matter of what is or is not considered rude. And, based on this down votes, comments and this answer, the majority of the SO community disagrees with me on this one.

Comment: +1 This answer is bad ass